# Kmeans - group by

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to do kmeans labels for `numClusters = 6` so that I can group by the labels later.

How do I select the columns to do kmeans on?

```
val clusterThis =  scaledDF.select($"id",$"setting1",$"setting2",$"setting3")

// dataset description lists six operation modes 
val operatingModes = 6 

// Cluster the data into two classes using KMeans
val numClusters = operatingModes
val numIterations = 20

import sqlContext.implicits._
val clusters = KMeans.train(clusterThis.rdd, numClusters, numIterations)
clusters.predict(clusterThis) 

//... join back on id
```

Comment: Are you using `ML` or `MLLib`?

Comment: I could use any if its avaliable, I think the above uses rdd/MLLib

Comment: Ah ML has a great exampple

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [KMeans's Example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html) the object uses just one column as `features`. In that example and by coincidence it has the same name. However, that name depends on you, but the important thing is that this column must be a `Vector` (dense or sparse).

Thus, you would need to *combine* your features (different columns) into one, for this task you can use a [VectorAssembler](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler).

*By the way, **K-means** doesn't work with **categorical features**.* You can read this post [K-means clustering for mixed numeric and categorical data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data) to notice the reasons.